# Page has a reference to Page Model, PageModel has a reference back to the page. Will memory be released?

Tags: c#, ios, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am building a `Xamarin.Forms` application.

Every `Page` when created has a reference to it's corresponding `PageModel`.

Now for purposes such as showing Alerts, Navigation etc. I will need a reference of the `Page` back in the `PageModel`.

Will this cause issues while releasing memory? (As both objects will always have a non null reference pointing to each other?)

If Yes, can something like a weak reference be used to fix this?

Comment: If you're following MVVM i think there is no need for Cyclic references. May be you should read Enterprise Application Patterns using Xamarin Forms.

Answer (score 1):

It will be, [sgen garbage collector also checks for object reachability](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/garbage-collector/sgen/#collection).